# Does driver-device interaction from one operating-system environment affect the driver-device interaction on another operating-system environment?

Tags: drivers

I'm working on another tutorial: if l used a computer with an SSD-hard-drive containing an instance of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed with a set of Nvidia GPUs loaded with the Nvidia-CUDA toolkit but swapped the SSD-hard-drive for a second SSD-hard-drive containing a separate instance of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and loaded with different drivers for the same Nvidia GPUs, would that interaction or install of new drivers on the second environment affect the interaction with the SSD hard-drive containing the Nvidia-CUDA toolkit drivers on the first environment?  I realize this is somewhat of a dumb question- in any case, I just thought I'd ask before I or someone else wants to know before learning the hard way.  Thanks!

Comment: You have two different hard drives, separated by space and time.  Why would what happens on one hard drive affect what happens on the other?

Comment: What I mean is- the driver-device interaction from one operating-system on one SSD hard-drive to another hard-drive.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Think about what you're asking.  In order for one hard drive to affect another (if only one is installed at a time), the rest of the hardware in the computer would have to "remember" something about that interaction.  It doesn't have this capability.  That's why we have hard drives in the first place: to remember things.

Comment: Technically, the drivers are installed *on the hard drive,* not on the computer itself.

Comment: I thought there would be some other layer of interaction affected by device-driver installs (eg BIOs).

Comment: Possible, but unlikely.  There's no way to know for sure without extensive analysis of the underlying hardware and software.

Comment: Thank you, sir- will report my findings later next week.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with [softwareengineering.se] as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: FYI, I conducted an experiment while creating a tutorial re: hashcat: after installing Nvidia 390-series drivers and the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit 10.0 on a mining rig equipped with 8 * Nvidia 8 GB Asus GeForce 1080 GTX GPU on Ubuntu 18.04 and then upgraded the drivers after swapping hard-drives to an instance of ethOS, the first Ubuntu instance failed to load hashcat benchmarks; here is my github gist: https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/d00a56a51127e73b70a2cdffcd75c9e2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would that interaction or install of new drivers on the second environment affect the interaction with the SSD hard-drive [...] on the first environment?

As long as the first SSD hard drive is not connected to a power supply and a PC (and as long as you keep it laying on a shelf at room temperature), it is next-to-impossible that it gets affected (except by flipping bits caused by cosmic rays, which I guess does not count). SSDs as well as other kind of hard disks are designed to keep their state as long as they get no electricity, that's the idea.

But if you mean *" ... when you revert the situation and exchange the second SSD back to the first"*, then the answer depends on if there are other persistent memory devices (like other hard disks) connected to the PC, which are not exchanged during the exchange of the SSDs. If there are such devices, it may be still unlikely, but not impossible the first environment might get affected in some way.